# Setting nginx and apache for whm panel

Tags: php, nginx, whm, fpm, mybb

(Sorry for my english, I use translator)
I have a MyBB forum with good attendance, Server: Centos 7, Whm + cpanel, Apache
Sites open for a long time, we decided to go nginx
I installed use one button nginx in whm panel
The site works faster but guests have become like 1 user as if they were assigned 1 ip
What other settings need to do to fix it?

I was told that: nginx is configured to ask a local apache to desserve php, but it's not forwarding the user IP

I was told that when using nginx it's better to use php-fpm with sock

I used google to find articles, I can not find the right folders for php-fpm and sock, In whm panel, everything is different, maybe you know a normal article How to configure it? I will be very grateful

Answer (score 0):

Hi @Alberto and welcome on SO for your first post.

By using nginx as a reverse proxy in front of apache the IP you see is currently the nginx one instead of the visitor's one

Cpanel has a tutorial to fix this https://support.cpanel.net/hc/en-us/articles/360051107513-Restoring-visitors-IP-with-mod-remoteip

I won't paste the full solution here, but if the link becomes broken in the future, basically you need to install the apache mod_remoteip.